# When hibernate gets initialized, to which db the Hibernate will be connected?

Tags: hibernate

An Hibernate core application has following files in the classpath directory with following entries:

In hibernate.properties:

```
  hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost/myAppDB1
```

and in hibernate.cfg.xml file we have:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">   
      jdbc:mysql://localhost/myAppDB2    
</property>
```

Given the files have the above statements in correct places in the file, when hibernate gets initialized, to which db the Hibernate will be connected?

a)myAppDB1/b)myAppDB2/c)cant decide/d)error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question contains the answer.  Have a close look at the `<property>` tag:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
    jdbc:mysql://localhost/myAppDB2
</property>
```

The database name is part of the connection URL, and it ends in `myAppDB2`.  So your answer is choice `b`, `myAppDB2`.

Comment: ...Thanks you very much